# Tokenfield for Bootstrap error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting the following error while trying to use Tokenfield for Bootstrap:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? The error happens at (about line 180):

```
this.$input.autocomplete(r)
```

`this.$input` points to an array containing the input field, but `this.$input.autocomplete` is undefined (when debugging from Chrome's console).

I've tried adding noconflict (as discussed [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/26)), but that didn't work.

Here's the manipulated html:

```
<div class="tokenfield form-control" style="width: 100%;">
    <input id="hident15" name="f14" type="text" required="" value="" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;">
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;">
    <input type="text" class="token-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="hident15-tokenfield" tabindex="0" style="min-width: 60px; width: 333px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out jQuery UI is also a dependency. This wasn't obvious from the documentation.

Comment: I got the same error and this worked, include jquery ui js and css